# Email to a contactList

Tags: php, sendmail, infusionsoft

how I can create a contactlist with this contact making function. for that am using a infusionsoft API
this is the API
    https://github.com/infusionsoft/PHP-iSDK

```
$conDat = array('FirstName' => 'Kamran', 'LastName' => 'Asadi',
'Email' => 'kamran_asadi15@yahoo.com');
 $conID = $myApp->addCon($conDat);
```

Anyone with some quick response?
And how can I pass a list of contacts to this function?